# Theorem: A change on the predictions implies a change on the features contributions of a linear model

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model

I want to prove that given a linear model $f_\beta$ and IID data with parameters $\beta_j$. That takes the form $f_\beta = \sum_j \cdot \beta_j\cdot x_j + c$.

Then if there is a change in the predictions $f_\beta(x) \neq f_\beta(x')$ then it implies a change in the contributions to the predictions

$ \sum_j \beta_j \cdot x_j + c \neq  \sum_j \beta_j \cdot x_j' $

- Is this a trivial demonstration?
- Is there any counterexample?
- Does it hold if the features are not IDD?

Comment: I think it's either completely trivial, or I've misunderstood you. f_b(x) is *defined* as sum_j beta_j x_j. (We can take x1 = 1 and beta1 = c to include the c term in the beta terms.) So writing f_b(x) != f_b(x') is exactly equal to writing sum_j beta_j x_j != sum_j beta_j x'_j.